# Не получается установить pygame

Tags: python, pycharm, pygame, pip, install

Я пытался установить Pygame с помощью команды pip install pygame, но выдает мне

Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла скрипта или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильнос
ть пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:4

- pip <<<<  install pygame

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Пробовал писать pip3 install pygame, ответ тот же.
Подумываю что у меня не установлен pip, но я не знаю как его устанавливать.
Помогите я уже запутался.

Answer (score 0):

100% вариант установки `pip` - https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py , копируете код `ctrl+a` вставляете в python файл и запускаете. Ещё можно просто пкм на этой страничке и в контекстном меню "сохранить как".